# How to include unit tests from outside Angular project after upgrade to v15?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Since Angular v15 the `require.context` function from `test.ts` configuration file was removed.

I was using require.context to make tests outside Angular project visible to Karma. Now this was removed:

```
const contextGlobal = require.context('../../../folderOutsideProject/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
contextGlobal.keys().map(contextGlobal);
```

How I can include tests from outside Angular project? (v15)

I tried creating a symlink between outsideFolder and project folder. It's not working.

EDIT:
from what I see in the source code, during the webpack compilation phase it is only included the projectSourceRoot path: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/dbcea96274122db128099967fec3d1ecceafe1ab/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/karma/find-tests-plugin.ts#L69

Comment: I see the `require.context` has been removed in the https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/23939. Looks like you need to use `include` option of [`ng test`](https://angular.io/cli/test)

Answer (score 0):

After migrating to angular v15, ended up with same issue however there were no useful resources to resolve it. So, went through the angular-cli source code to fix this.

**Reason:**

In v15, angular team had added find-test-plugin to find and load the *.spec.ts file internally rather than asking us to find and load the tests files using require.context() webpack API externally.

Now, the tests are identified based on relative paths from **sourceRoot** and **include** configurations inside **angular.json**

Sample Project structure:

- root/app/
- root/test/

Consider all '*.spec.ts' files are under test directory which is outside app directory.

**Changes in angular.json:**

```
{
  "sourceRoot": "root",
  "architect": {
      "test": {
         "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
         "options": {
            "main": "root/test/test.ts",
            "polyfills": [ "zone.js","zone.js/testing" ],
            "include": ["test/**/*.spec.ts"],
        .....
        .....
}
```

You can remove the **main** configuration if not needed. But if you need it then make sure to remove these two lines:

> const contextGlobal = require.context('../../../folderOutsideProject/', true, /.spec.ts$/);
> contextGlobal.keys().map(contextGlobal);

**Changes in tsconfig.spec.json:**

```
{
   "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types": ["jasmine"]
      },
   "include": [ "root/test/test.ts", "root/test/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```